# IEnumerable - Return items in range either side of element

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I need to get an element from an IEnumerable and then return itself and a range of elements on either side.

So, something like this:

```
var enumerable = new[] {54, 107, 24, 223, 134, 65, 36, 7342, 812, 96, 106};
var rangeSize = 2;
var range = enumerable.MySelectRange(x => x == 134, rangeSize);
```

would return something like `{ 24, 223, 134, 65, 36 }`.

(This project uses .Net 3.5)

**EDIT**
Ok, people seem to be getting hung up on the array of ints.
I've changed the example to hopefully make it more clear what I'm after.

Bear in mind that this isn't necessarily for an `IEnumerable<int>`, but will actually be an `IEnumerable<TSomething>`.

Comment: Jon Skeet implemented some kind of SmartEnumerable with which you can enumerate with index, so you can limit the index from specified value +/- the range. That's just an idea.. Take a look. http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2007/07/27/smart-enumerations.aspx

Comment: Or you can simply use the for loop and manage indexes.

Comment: What if there's more than one occurrence of the range center (i.e. 5) ? Should you return the first window, or all windows ?

Comment: @digEmAll: Good question... There's not a chance of duplication in the current implementation, but it's something that I'd need to bear in mind if I want to make this a general solution.

Comment: @Kornelije Petak: Yeah, I thought about that, but it is annoying not to be able to do it in LINQ :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This extension method finds the first element in the sequence satisfying a given predicate, and then returns that element along with a certain number of its neighbouring elements. It handles the end cases.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FirstAndNeighbours<T>(
  this IEnumerable<T> source,
  Func<T,bool> predicate,
  int numOfNeighboursEitherSide)
{
  using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
  {
    var precedingNeighbours = new Queue<T>(numOfNeighboursEitherSide);
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
      var current = enumerator.Current;
      if (predicate(current))
      {
        //We have found the first matching element. First, we must return
        //the preceding neighbours.
        foreach (var precedingNeighbour in precedingNeighbours)
          yield return precedingNeighbour;

        //Next, return the matching element.
        yield return current;

        //Finally, return the succeeding neighbours.
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfNeighboursEitherSide; ++i)
        {
          if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

          yield return enumerator.Current;
        }
        yield break;
      }
      //No match yet, keep track of this preceding neighbour.
      if (precedingNeighbours.Count >= numOfNeighboursEitherSide)
        precedingNeighbours.Dequeue();
      precedingNeighbours.Enqueue(current);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks great to me... Just tested it, and it seems to work well. Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can obtain the index of the middle element:

```
var enumerable = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

int range = 2;
int index = 10;

enumerable.Skip(index-range).Take(range)
.Union(enumerable.Skip(index).Take(1))
.Union(
    enumerable.Skip(index+1).Take(range)
).Dump();
```

(the `Dump()` call is for [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/))

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Gabe's comment, got rid of the two extra `Skip()`/`Take()`:

```
enumerable.Skip((index < range) ? 0 : index-range)
          .Take(((index < range) ? index : range) + range + 1)
          .Dump();
```

Comment: Why on Earth would you enumerate 3 times instead of just doing `Take(2 * range + 1)`?

Comment: Because it wouldn't work when the index is close to the lower bound (0 < index-range).

Comment: And you think iterating the whole sequence 3 times is better than a couple `if` statements?

Comment: No, it's just another way (more readable, maybe) to do it. Why is the sequence iterated three times, anyway (talking about the edited version)?

Comment: Every time you run `Skip`, it has to start enumerating the whole sequence over from the beginning. If the sequence was the result of a DB query, it would have to requery the DB, for example.

Comment: You're partially right about the DB query: Linq generates a single query which would (inefficiently) make two UNIONs. The updated version works in a single pass, however.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Updated answer due to question update ****

an extension method should do it, now supports any type `T`

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Range<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T,bool> selector, int size)
{
    Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
    bool found = false;
    int count = 0;
    foreach(T item in enumerable)
    {
            if(found)
            {
                if(count++ < size)
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(queue.Count>size)
                    queue.Dequeue();

                if(selector(item))
                {
                    found = true;
                    foreach(var stackItem in queue)
                        yield return stackItem;

                    yield return item;


                }
                else
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

usage is close to what you required

```
 var enumerable = new[] {54, 107, 24, 223, 134, 65, 36, 7342, 812, 96, 106};
 Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",enumerable.ToArray()));
 var rangeSize = 2;
 var range = enumerable.Range((x) => x == 134, rangeSize);
 Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",range.ToArray()));
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=ACKDD76841

Comment: Ok, that looks promising... Can you think of a way to make it work with an IEnumerable<T>? The actual usage won't just be an array of ints!

Comment: This is not even close to what the OP wants! You're looking at all values in the Enumerable and returning all of them that are plus/minus `size` of `rangeMiddle`. What the OP wants is to find the first item that meets a condition and returns the `rangeSize` prior and `rangeSize` successive elements.

Comment: @NeilD - now updated to support any T, and you're new requirement

Answer (score 1):

The following gives correct answers for non-linear sequences and is efficient, e.g:

```
const int PivotValue = 5;
const int RangeSize = 2;

int[] enumerable = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000 };

IEnumerable<int> range = enumerable.PivotRange(PivotValue, RangeSize);}

//3, 4, 5, 600, 700.
```

**Code - Generic Version**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> PivotRange<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, T pivot, int size) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    T[] left = new T[size];
    int lCount = 0, rCount = 0;
    IEnumerator<T> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        T item = enumerator.Current;

        if (item.CompareTo(pivot) == 0)
        {
            int start = lCount > size ? lCount % size : 0;
            int end = Math.Min(size, lCount);

            for (int i = start; i < start + end; i++)
                yield return left[i % size];

            yield return pivot;

            while (enumerator.MoveNext() && rCount++ < size)
                yield return enumerator.Current;

            break;
        }

        if (size <= 0) continue;

        left[lCount++ % size] = item;
    }
}
```

**Update - Unit Tests**

```
[Test]
public void Linear()
{
    const int PivotValue = 5;
    const int RangeSize = 2;

    int[] enumerable = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    int[] range = enumerable.PivotRange(PivotValue, RangeSize).ToArray();

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, range);
}

[Test]
public void NonLinear()
{
    const int PivotValue = 5;
    const int RangeSize = 2;

    int[] enumerable = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000 };

    int[] range = enumerable.PivotRange(PivotValue, RangeSize).ToArray();

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 3, 4, 5, 600, 700 }, range);
}

[Test]
public void NoLeft()
{
    const int PivotValue = 5;
    const int RangeSize = 2;

    int[] enumerable = new[] { 5, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000 };

    int[] range = enumerable.PivotRange(PivotValue, RangeSize).ToArray();

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 5, 600, 700 }, range);
}

[Test]
public void NoRight()
{
    const int PivotValue = 5;
    const int RangeSize = 2;

    int[] enumerable = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    int[] range = enumerable.PivotRange(PivotValue, RangeSize).ToArray();

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 3, 4, 5 }, range);
}

[Test]
public void ZeroRange()
{
    const int PivotValue = 5;
    const int RangeSize = 0;

    int[] enumerable = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    int[] range = enumerable.PivotRange(PivotValue, RangeSize).ToArray();

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 5 }, range);
}

[Test]
public void LeftShorterThanRange()
{
    const int PivotValue = 5;
    const int RangeSize = 2;

    int[] enumerable = new[] { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    int[] range = enumerable.PivotRange(PivotValue, RangeSize).ToArray();

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 4, 5, 6, 7 }, range);
}

[Test]
public void RightShorterThanRange()
{
    const int PivotValue = 5;
    const int RangeSize = 2;

    int[] enumerable = new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, };

    int[] range = enumerable.PivotRange(PivotValue, RangeSize).ToArray();

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { 3, 4, 5, 6 }, range);
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be restricted to `int` and it doesn't work. I get an exeception in the `for` loop.

Comment: @Gabe Have converted to generic - didn't see question edit. Looking int exception...

Comment: @Gabe I have added some basic unit tests for common cases. What sequence caused your exception?

Comment: I got the exception on the OP's test sequence.

Comment: @Gabe I have just reviewed my first post and tested the code. There is no exception with my original post and the OP's test sequence. Not sure where you got that from? The edit history is there... "it doesn't work" is a bit damning of my post. The only exception case I have fixed is when rangeSize is zero, your solution also has an exception with this.

Comment: I don't know why it's working for you and not me. I just pasted your `PivotRange` function in from Revision 1 and ran `new[] { 54, 107, 24, 223, 134, 65, 36, 7342, 812, 96, 106 }.PivotRange(134, 2).ToArray()`. I get an exception evaluating `left[j]` because `j` is -1.

Comment: @chibacity let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2733/discussion-between-gabe-and-chibacity)

Comment: @Gabe Sorry, but this is confusing. You said that my original post broke with the OP's test sequence. The example you have just given is not the OP's test sequence. If you use the test sequence it's fine with my original post. There was a bug, but it has long since been fixed...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
var enumerable = new[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
var rangeSize = 2;
var index = enumerable.FirstOrDefault(x=> x == 2);
var range = enumerable.Skip(index + 1).Take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a queue-based version, only I implement my own queue (unlike the others that use `Queue`). The advantage of implementing my own queue is that it is just slightly more efficient.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MySelectRange<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                              Func<T, bool> selector,
                                              int rangeSize)
{
    var firstN = new T[rangeSize];
    int pos = 0;
    bool found = false;

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        if (found)
            if (pos++ <= rangeSize)
                yield return item;
            else
                break;
        if (selector(item))
        {
            found = true;
            for (int i = Math.Max(0, pos - rangeSize); i < pos; i++)
                yield return firstN[i % rangeSize];
            yield return item;
            pos = 0;
        }
        else if (rangeSize > 0)
            firstN[pos++ % rangeSize] = item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far the elements are unique, below function will work for you.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MySelectRange<T>(this IEnumerable<T> me, Func<T, bool> pred, int range)
{
      var first = me.TakeWhile(i => !pred(i)).TakeLast(range);
      var second = me.SkipWhile(i => !pred(i)).Take(range + 1);
      return first.Concat(second);
}
```

NOTE: The TakeLast seems to be from Rx library

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetRange<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int rangeSize, T value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < enumerable.Count(); ++i)
        {
            if (enumerable.ElementAt(i).Equals(value))
            {
                for (int j = Math.Max(0, i - rangeSize); j < Math.Min(i + rangeSize + 1, enumerable.Count()); ++j)
                {
                    yield return enumerable.ElementAt(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this looks like it should work, you should materialize the enumerable into a list if you are going to treat it like one.  As it stands, you are enumerating through the list several times per iteration with `Count` and `ElementAt`.

Comment: @Gideon Agreed, this will not perform very well with large lists, it will get exponentially worse. Materializing the whole input kind of defeats the stream based nature of enumerating though.